# A triangle with side lengths x, x^2 and x^3

Tags: geometry, triangles

If I have a triangle with side lengths x, x^2, and x^3, what are the possible values of x expressed in interval notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that $x>0$. We divide all the sides by $x$ so our sides are $1$, $x$, and $x^2$. You can apply three times the triangle inequality:
$$1+x\geq x^2$$
$$1+x^2\geq x$$
$$x^2+x\geq 1$$

The first equation restricts $x$ to $-\phi^{-1}<x<\phi$, with $\phi$ being the golden ratio:
$$\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$$

The second equation is always true.

The third equation restricts $x$ to $x<-\phi$ or $\phi^{-1}<x$.

So including all the constratints, we end up with:
$$\phi^{-1}<x<\phi$$

Comment: I understand how the first equation restricts x, but how does the third equation restrict x?

Comment: Yes it does, as $x>\phi^{-1}$

Comment: Oh I see it now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a triangle to exist, it's necessary that the sum of the lengths of any two sides of a triangle must be greater than or equal to the length of the third side.
Hence, by the lengths that you suppose, you must have that

$$(1)\ x<x^3+x^2$$
$$(2)\ x^2<x^3+x$$
$$(3)\ x^3<x^2+x$$

By (1), $$x\in \left(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}-1),+\infty\right)\cup \left(\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{5}-1),0\right)$$
By (2), $$x\in (0,+\infty)$$
By (3), you have that $$x\in \left(-\infty,\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{5}+1)\right)\cup \left(0,\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}+1)\right).$$

Take the intersection of the three sets, and you get that
$$x\in \left(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}-1),\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}+1)\right).$$